# Batchwise convolutions – for each batch element a different weight

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch, convolution

Given an input `x` which has a shape of `(32, 4, 16)`. To this input, a convolution (conv1d) shall be applied. Note that, there are `4` input channels. Each of these channels has a dimensionality of `16`. The batch size is `32`. In the following, it is assumed that the number of output channels shall be `8`. Therefore, the `weight` has the shape `(8, 4, 1)`

Overall, we got the following code:

```
batch_size = 32
input_channels = 4
output_channels = 8
dim = 16

x = torch.zeros(size=(batch_size, input_channels, dim))
weight = torch.rand(size=(output_channels, input_channels, 1))
y = F.conv1d(x, weight)
```

**Now to my question:**
Instead of applying the *same* weight to each batch element, I want to apply to each batch element a *different* weight. In other words, the `weight` must have the shape `(32, 8, 4, 1)`.
How I can implement this batchwise convolution operation?

If `weight` is assigned to `torch.rand(size=(batch_size, output_channels, input_channels, 1))` then the code does not work.
Ofcourse there exists a simple solution which is based on a for-loop.
I am looking for a solution without a for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conv1d with a kernel of shape `(1)` is the same as broadcasted multiply with sum-reduction. Specifically

```py
# x.shape (32, 4, 16)
# weight.shape (8, 4, 1)

y = (x.unsqueeze(1) * weight.unsqueeze(0)).sum(dim=2)
# equivalent to y = F.conv1d(x, weight)
# equivalent to y = torch.einsum('bin,oin->bon', x, weight)
```

So if we assume weight has shape `(32, 8, 4, 1)` then we just don't need to broadcast over the first dimension.

```py
# x.shape (32, 4, 16)
# weight.shape (32, 8, 4, 1)

y = (x.unsqueeze(1) * weight).sum(dim=2)
# equivalent to y = torch.einsum('bin,boin->bon', x, weight)
```